# Chrome and Firefox parse Date differently

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I found chrome parse some date pattern differently,  the time string `"2015-07-13T07:30:00"` got from `moment(time).format()`

Chrome:

```
new Date("2015-07-13T07:30:00").toISOString()
// output "2015-07-13T07:30:00.000Z"
```

Firefox:

```
new Date("2015-07-13T07:30:00").toISOString()
// output "2015-07-12T23:30:00.000Z"
```

Firefox's output is my desired output, Chrome automatically assumes the timezone is utf offset 0, how can I get fix this?

Comment: You tagged the question with the Moment.js tag - have you read the documentation for parsing dates with that library? If you're willing to use it then that's a perfectly good way to go.

Comment: Specifically, check the output of `moment("2015-07-13T07:30:00")` on both browsers.